# How to use query result in hive script

Tags: hive

I have tried the below but it's not working.

cat nds.ksh

```
var=$(hive -e "datediff(CONCAT(y, '-', (m + 1), '-', '01'), CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', '01')) FROM (SELECT month(current_date) as m, year(current_date) as y, day(current_date)) tabl1;")
```

tt.hql

```
select
sum(price)/ ${hiveconf:ndays}
from  sales_aly
GROUP BY sales_month;

hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you created one more duplicated question?

Comment: Your shell file does not contain call of main hive script... Did you call nds.ksh before this: hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql

Comment: it seems this should be second line in nds.ksh file: hive -hiveconf ndays=$var -f tt.hql